# How to convert fom string to hexadecimal?

Tags: c++

I have the following `string: s="80"`. I need to put this in an 
`unsigned char k[]. The unsigned char should look like this: unsigned char k[]={0x38,0x34}, where 0x38=8 and 0x34=0` These are the hexadecimal values for 8 and 0. How to do this? Need some help!

Please give some code. Thx

I am working on ubuntu c++ code. THX!

I use this for an encryption! I need 0x38 in an unsigned char.PLEASE HELP! Need some code:)

EDIT:

HOW TO OBTAIN THE DEC/CHAR VALUE AND PUT IT IN AN `unsigned char k[]`?
I've realised that it's ok if in the `unsigned char [] i have the dec values {56,52} of the 8 and 0 that i have in the string!`

Comment: You have to tgenerate the actual code, or you have to access the string each element at a time?

Comment: can't you just do s.c_str()?  What are you going to do with the array afterwards?

Comment: is this for a homework question?

Comment: This is unclear. If the string is "80" then it contains the sequence of bytes 0x38 and 0x34. Use `unsigned char k[] = {s[0],s[1]};`?

Comment: and actually 0x38 and 0x34 are not representations of characters 8 and 0., but 8 and 4.

Comment: @Benoit: Please lookup the ASCII table. For over 30 years, 0x38 == '8' and 0x34 == '4'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want this string converted as ASCII (or UTF-8) it is already in the correct format.

```
std::string  s="80";

std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(s[0]) << "\n";
std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(s[1]) << "\n";
```

If you want it in an int array, then just copy it:

```
int   data[2];
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), data);
```

Comment: thx! is there a way not to us std::cout ? i don't want to print the hex values! thx

Comment: use a `std::ostringstream`, and then use `.str()` to get a string: `std::ostringstream os; os << "0x" << std::hex << ... ; const string s = os.str();`

Answer (score 3):

I think that no matter you store `'8'` or `0x39`, they will be present as the same binary numbers by the computer.

Comment: You're absolutely right wong2. Everything is integer behind the scene. @just me: just iterate over your string (std::string or whatever contains your sequence of chars), and insert these characters in your array. You're done.

Comment: ASCII has now 1-based index! (seriously it is 0x38). And +1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not really understand what you are asking.

The following are synonyms:

```
std::string s = "\x38\x30";
std::string s = "80";
```

As the following are synonyms:

```
char c = '8',  s = '0' ;
char c = s[0], s = s[1];
char c = 0x38, s = 0x30;
```

It is exactly the same (except if your base encoding is not ASCII). This is not an encryption.

Comment: i need to put the decimal values of 8 into an unsigned char. can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @just me: unsigned char d = 8U;

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s = "80";
unsigned char * pArray = new unsigned char[ s.size() ];

const char * p = s.c_str();
unsigned char * p2 = pArray;

while( *p )
   *p2++ = *p++;

delete []pArray;
```

Comment: you forget that std::string can include the null character in the middle (okay this is not the case here)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. I did not write these codes. I found I like you

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

namespace {
   const std::string test="mahmutefe";
}

int main() {
   std::ostringstream result;
   result << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::uppercase;
   std::copy(test.begin(), test.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(result, " "));
   std::cout << test << ":" << result.str() << std::endl;
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

convert that string to a char array, then subrtact '0' from each char.